# Access to 2 elements of the same array in VHDL on each clock edge

Tags: matrix, multidimensional-array, vhdl, xilinx

How can I access 2 elements of a 2d array in the same process and on each clock edge?

```
entity test is
generic   (N     : integer  := 8;
       N_MAX : integer  :=1944;
       O_MAX : integer  :=20;
       M_MAX : integer  :=324;
       K_MAX : integer  :=1620);
Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
       rst : in STD_LOGIC;
a   : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 downto 0);
       b  : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 downto 0)`);
end test;

architecture Behavioral of test is
type t1 is array (0 to 323,0 to 19) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

signal tab:t1;
```

`

Would appreciate some help,thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any multidimensional array can be implemented as a single dimensional array (linear array, as in memory). Use two read back multiplexers which are each implied by by selected name (e.g. tab(dim1, dim2)), When synthesized your multidimensional array will have it's dimensions promoted to powers of two. Think hardware. Consider providing a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Only one of your generic constants is used in your code snippet.

Comment: Remember, that in hardware, you don't read "2d array" but some kind of memory, like BRAM, or distributed ram. No matter what you choose, it is not a problem so read 2 elements in one clock cycle.

Comment: The determination that an (array) object is sequentially stored (registered, latched, memory) is whether or not is updated for any change in a right hand side element in an assignment or is conditional assigned (based on a value or signal event).  A signal object can be simply a net or collection of nets. A variable or constant object can be a value or collection of values. You don't demonstrate an assignment to tab, part of the call for a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example and to think in hardware terms.  Your snippet doesn't convey hardware without assignment and events, it's abstract.